# Descobrir os números que menos aparecem nos registros

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Saudações pessoal. Tenho uma tabela mais ou menos assim:

```
reg  num0 num1 num2 num3 num4 num4
1     4    2    5    8    10   15   
2     3    7    8    15   20   21
3     14   10   6    21   17   1
4     1    4    8    10   16   7
5     9    3    2    1    8    15
```

eu preciso descobrir quais os números mais atrasados, em ordem.
E.g:

- Número 21 -> atrasado a 3 registros (porque a última vez que apareceu foi no registro número 2).
- Número 5 -> atrasado a 5 registros (porque a última vez que apareceu foi no registro número 1).

Já tentei de algumas formas mas sem sucesso.
Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou dividir a lógica em etapas separadas para facilitar.

Primeiro, vamos ver onde foi a última ocorrência do número 21, por exemplo:

```
SELECT    reg
FROM      tabelaMaisOuMenosAssim
WHERE     21 IN (num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5)
ORDER BY  reg DESC
LIMIT     1;
```

Uma vez obtido este registro, basta contar quantos existem depois dele. No seu exemplo, teríamos recebido `3` como retorno.

Para saber quantos vieram depois (pode-se usar `>=` se quiser incluir a linha corrente):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS atrasado WHERE reg > 3
```

Caso esteja usando alguma linguagem auxiliar de suporte, isto pode ser feito com duas *queries* e uso de variáveis.

### Juntando as duas coisas

Podemos fazer uma *subquery* para obter o resultado numa operação só:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS atrasado
FROM   tabelaMaisOuMenosAssim
WHERE  reg >= (
   SELECT    reg
   FROM      tabelaMaisOuMenosAssim
   WHERE     21 IN (num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5)
   ORDER BY  reg DESC
   LIMIT     1
);
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91d32f/2)**.

### Caso vá utilizar constantemente este recurso

Você pode criar uma `FUNCTION` que faça parte da base de dados, em vez de usar a *query* inteira toda vez que precisar obter um valor:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pegaAtrasado(numero int)
RETURNS int
RETURN (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   tabelaMaisOuMenosAssim
  WHERE  reg >= (
    SELECT    reg
    FROM      tabelaMaisOuMenosAssim
    WHERE     numero IN (num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5)
    ORDER BY  reg DESC
    LIMIT     1
  )
);
```

Modo de usar (simples assim):

```
SELECT pegaAtrasado( 21 );
SELECT pegaAtrasado(  5 );
SELECT pegaAtrasado(  1 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e2b/1)**.

Comment: @thiago a maior vantagem da FUNCTION direto no DB é que você vai apenas precisar dos SELECT() no PHP, sem executar a query toda vez (A function é criada direto no MySQL, e uma vez só, e permanece lá, não é feita no PHP). A vantagem de fazer como você fez é que fica mais fácil dar manutenção, pois você vai mexer apenas no lado PHP, apesar de ter menos performance (a diferença costuma ser pequena).

Comment: eu estive analisando o código mas, dessa forma não estou conseguindo realizar a consulta desses atrasados até certa data. Estou fazendo assim: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS atrasado FROM resultado_loteria WHERE codCadastro >= ( SELECT codCadastro FROM resultado_loteria WHERE codModalidade = 2 AND 1 IN (num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12,num13,num14) AND dataConcurso BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-11-03' ORDER BY codCadastro DESC LIMIT 1 )`. Para mostrar estou usando um laço "for" de 1 a 25 quando chamo a classe.